# Another convenient variable change for solving an integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to compute the following integral:

$$\int_0^{\sqrt\pi/2} \int_x^{\sqrt\pi/2} \int_1^3 \sin y^2 \, dz \, dy \, dx$$

The term $\sin y^2$ is difficult to integrate, so it is yelling 'Change the variables!'. The thing is I haven't figured out how yet. I wanted to ask for suggestions.

Comment: $$\int_0^{\sqrt{\pi}/2}\int_x^{\sqrt{\pi}/2} \sin y^2 \, dy dx = \int_0^{\sqrt{\pi}/2}\int_0^y \sin y^2 dx dy = \ldots$$

Comment: The innermost integral is trivial: As $z$ goes from $1$ to $3$, the function $\sin y^2$ does not change at all, so you're integrating a constant and you get $2\sin y^2$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Thanks for your help, I answered the question using your suggestions, In case you'd like to check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the suggestions above, I think maybe it is more useful to recur to Fubini's Theorem:

$$\int_0^{\sqrt\pi/2} \int_x^{\sqrt\pi/2} \int_1^3 \sin y^2 \, dz \, dy \, dx=\int_0^{\sqrt\pi/2} \int_0^{y} \int_1^3 \sin y^2 \, dz \, dy \, dx$$ 
$$=\int_0^{\sqrt\pi/2} \int_0^{y} 2 \sin y^2 \,  \, dy \, dx$$ 
$$=\int_0^{\sqrt\pi/2} 2y \sin y^2  \, dx$$ 
$$1-\sqrt2/2$$

Answer (score 1):

If $y = \sqrt{u}$,  $\sin y^2 = \sin u$, $dy = \dfrac{du}{2\sqrt{u}}$ and $x \le y \le \sqrt{\pi}/{2}$ becomes $x^2 \le u \le \pi/4$.  But I don't think you'll find $\sin(u)/\sqrt{u}$ any easier to integrate than $\sin(y^2)$.  The antiderivative is non-elementary (a [Fresnel integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral)).  A better idea is to interchange the order of the $y$ and $x$ integrations.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I answered the question using your suggestions, In case you'd like to check it out.